# What is the radius of convergence of this power series?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, power-series

The series is defined as $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{(4+(-1)^k)^{3k}}$. I tried to use the formula (R being the radius of convergence and $a_k=\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^k)^{3k}}$) $R= \frac{1}{\limsup_{k\to\infty}|a_k|^{\frac{1}{k}}}$. I'm not sure if I can use this though because we just used it for power series with $x^k$ and not $x^{2k}$ or even $x^{k^2}$ so can I also use this formula in these cases? I continued:
$$R= \frac{1}{\limsup_{k\to\infty}|\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^k)^{3k}}|^{\frac{1}{k}}}=\frac{1}{\limsup_{k\to\infty}|(\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^k)^{3}})^k|^{\frac{1}{k}}}=\frac{1}{\limsup_{k\to\infty}|(\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^k)^{3}})|}=\frac{1}{\limsup_{k\to\infty}(\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^k)^{3}})}$$ Now using the subsequences $a_{k_n}=2n$ we get $$\frac{1}{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^{2n})^{3}})}=\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{(4+1)^{3}})}=125=\frac{1}{\limsup_{k\to\infty}(\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^k)^{3}})}$$ (since $a_{k_n}=2n+1$ yields $$\frac{1}{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^{2n+1})^{3}})}=\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{(4-1)^{3}})}=27=\frac{1}{\liminf_{k\to\infty}(\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^k)^{3}})}$$). So the interval of convergence should be this (since it is defined around the point $x_0=0$): the series converges for $x\in(-125,125)$. When i just tested if this works out fine and entered this series for $x=10$ into WolframAlpha it told me that it diverges which isn't quite what should happen right? I feel like i made a mistake but I'm not sure what it was (my best guess is that I can't use this formula when the power series is defined with $x^{2k}$ for example and not $x^k$.

Comment: You have, due to the absolute convergence of geometric series, $$f(x)=\sum_n\frac{x^{4n}}{5^{6n}}+\frac{x^2}{3^3}\sum_n\frac{x^{4n}}{3^{6n}}=\frac1{1-x^4/5^6}+\frac{x^2}{27(1-x^4/3^6)}.$$ The singular points can be directly read off.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{(4+(-1)^k)^{3k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(x^2)}^k}{(4+(-1)^k)^{3k}}$$
So sub $z=x^2$ and find radius of convergence of this series, call it $R’$. Then radius of convergence of the original series is $R=\sqrt{R’}$.

Comment: Oh this works? Thank you! What do i do when it's something like $x^{(k^2)}$?

Comment: Its not a power series then.